# Wrong number of questions shown on network profile

Tags: bug, questions, linked-accounts, network-profile

I noticed what I think is a bug on my network profile accounts list.

I currently have 9 questions on Super User (and that's correctly shown on [my Super User profile](https://superuser.com/users/441767/danicotra)) but if I look at [my network profile accounts list](https://stackexchange.com/users/1081773/danicotra?tab=accounts) it counts only 8 questions for Super User.

Comment: Looks like the [undelete](https://superuser.com/posts/1217934/timeline) event didn't schedule your Super User profile to be processed for the network accounts batch.

Comment: things got back to normal as I made a new question on Super User, now the counting is correct on network profile too